# Convert coordinates into GeoJSON data

Tags: 7

I have the module [Google Store Locator](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_store_locator). It works perfectly. The data are fed via [GeoJSON views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_geojson) module.

I have used [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to feed all the data.

The problem is that the coordinates of the stores are geocoded, and if, for some reason, the system does not find the correct address, they will be empty.

I have the coordinates in a database, but don't know how to feed into the system with this configuration. I even try to hard-insert the data into the table `field_data_gsl_geofield` but for some reason it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It's a little unclear from your question where the issue is. Is it that some of your points show up and others don't? Because from the way you asked the question you're already converting the data to geojson with Views_geojson.

Comment: The problem lies when saving the node. The field location, with its corresponding entry in the database table `field_data_gsl_geofield` does not put coordinates. I finally changed the config to use always coordinates, and I copy from the database directly into the fields, manually.

Comment: So, are you using the location module or geofield? Those are the modules that store your points. ViewsGeojson converts the points, you don't need to store the json in the db, why would you?